# MySQL - How to select Multiple rows from Multiple tables

Tags: mysql, rows

I have a question about a SQL statement, for some reason my script is not working properly..
This is the Scenario; I have 6 tables

```
Patient
-PatientID
-PatientName
-EmployerID FK to employer.EmployerID.

Employer
-EmployerID
-EmployerName

Carrier
-CarrierID
-CarrierName

Appointment
-AppointmentID
-AptDateTime
-PatientID FK to patient.PatientID

InsurancePlan
-PlanID
-GroupName
-EmployerID FK to employer.EmployerID
-CarrierID FK to carrier.CarrierID

Inssub
-InsubID
-DateEffective
-PlanID FK to insplan.PlanID
-Suscriber FK to patient.PatientID
```

My Script: I need get all the rows from those 5 tables. I am not really good for SQL Indexes validation, that's why my script is not working properly !

```
SELECT p.PatientName, e.EmployerName, c.CarrierName, ip.GroupName, a.AptDateTime, i.DateEffective

FROM patient p, employer e, inssub i, InsurancePlan ip, carrier c, appointment a

WHERE e.EmployerNum = p.EmployerNum AND 
      i.Subscriber = p.PatientID AND
      i.PlanID = ip.PlanID AND
      ip.CarrierID = c.CarrierID AND
      ip.employerID = e.EmployerID AND
      ip.PlanID = i.PlanID AND
          a.PatientID = p.PatientID AND
          a.DateTStamp > '2013/01/01' AND    
      a.AptDateTime != '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler if you use explicit JOINS rather than comma-delimited tables:

```
SELECT p.PatientName, e.EmployerName, c.CarrierName, ip.GroupName, a.AptDateTime, i.DateEffective
FROM patient p
JOIN employer e ON p.EmployerID = e.EmployerID
JOIN insuranceplan ip ON e.EmployerID = ip.EmployerID
JOIN carrier c ON ip.CarrierID = c.CarrierID
JOIN appointment a ON p.PatientID = a.PatientID
JOIN inssub i ON p.PatientID = i.Subscriber AND ip.PlanID = i.PlanID
WHERE a.DateTStamp > '2013/01/01'
  AND a.AptDateTime != '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: @Jay, Updated to note additional column.  If this doesn't do what you need, can you post some sample data, and what result you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.PatientName, e.EmployerName, c.CarrierName, ip.GroupName, a.AptDateTime
FROM Patient p JOIN Employer e ON p.EmployerId=e.EmployerId
JOIN Appointment a ON p.PatientId= a.PatientId
JOIN InsurancePlan ip ON ip.EmployerId=e.EmployerId
JOIN Carrier c ON c.CarrierId=ip.CarrierId
Join Inssub i ON i.PlanId=ip.PlanId
WHERE a.DateTStamp > '2013/01/01'
AND a.AptDateTime != '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Try this and see

Comment: Missing `employer` join. And `inssub` isn't really needed for the SELECT used.  Are you adding something that I missed?

Comment: I include the employer in very first statement it self.

Comment: Missed that - my apologies.  But the `inssub` table shouldn't be needed here.

Comment: No prob bro. It might can't see clearly because it put it together.

Comment: Sorry was my mistake,i missed the inssub's DateEffective on select statement (updated) i've tried this script, but still not getting all the records i have on database,. i have 3 in total, just returned 2

Comment: Check out the time maybe because of that it's not coming or what?check that